# Incrementing a member into an object, error

Tags: variables, powershell

```
$list = @()
$cels = @()
$objResult = @()

$list = 
"1384630490 1 68 4 adm-media03 4184066 4184062 0 nbpem CLIENT  POLICY SBT_windows_srv_siteservers_isolation  SCHED Diff  EXIT STATUS 0 (the requested operation was successfully completed)",
"1385148607 1 68 4 adm-media01 4277480 4277295 0  nbpem CLIENT   POLICY   SCHED Full  EXIT STATUS 87 (media close error)"

$i = 0
foreach ($row in $list){

        $cels = $row.split(" ")

        foreach ($cel in $cels) {

            $objResult += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                "T$i" = $cel
            }
            $i++
        }      
}
```

and the result of

> $objResult | gm

is:

```
Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
T0          NoteProperty System.String T0=1384630490
```

Why  is not adding all the propierties intoo the object?
Every new property should be inserted after iteration of $i with the value of $cell
And shomething is not ok, i can`t figure it out what is the problem.
It should look like:

```
Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
T0          NoteProperty System.String T0=1384630490
T1          NoteProperty System.String T1=1
T2          NoteProperty System.String T2=68
T3          NoteProperty System.String T3=4
T4          NoteProperty System.String T4=adm-media03
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're creating a new PSObject in every iteration of your inner-most foreach loop.

Instead of doing that, you might want to use Add-Member like this:

```
$list = @()
$cels = @()
$objResult = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

$list = 
"1384630490 1 68 4 adm-media03 4184066 4184062 0 nbpem CLIENT  POLICY SBT_windows_srv_siteservers_isolation  SCHED Diff  EXIT STATUS 0 (the requested operation was successfully completed)",
"1385148607 1 68 4 adm-media01 4277480 4277295 0  nbpem CLIENT   POLICY   SCHED Full  EXIT STATUS 87 (media close error)"

$i = 0
foreach ($row in $list) {

    $cels = $row.split(" ")

    foreach ($cel in $cels) {
        $objResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "T$i" -Value $cel
        $i++
    }      
}
```

Comment: T$i property must contain the value of 1st element from $list's row1 and the value of the 1st element from $list`s row2.
Like this is adding in T$i+n:

T0 
----
1384630490
1385148607

something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one object per row, you need to accumulate all the properties into a single hash before you create the object:

```
$list = @()
$cels = @()
$objResult = @()


$list = 
"1384630490 1 68 4 adm-media03 4184066 4184062 0 nbpem CLIENT  POLICY SBT_windows_srv_siteservers_isolation  SCHED Diff  EXIT STATUS 0 (the requested operation was successfully completed)",
"1385148607 1 68 4 adm-media01 4277480 4277295 0  nbpem CLIENT   POLICY   SCHED Full  EXIT STATUS 87 (media close error)"

    foreach ($row in $list){

    $i = 0

    $PropertyHash = @{}

    $cels = $row.split(" ")

    foreach ($cel in $cels) {

        $PropertyHash +=  @{
            "T$i" = $cel
          }
        $i++

    } 

  $objResult += $objResult += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $PropertyHash     
}

$objResult
```

Right now, you're creating one object with a single property for every item in the row split.

Comment: "$objResult += $objResult +=" ??
and it can only be a maximum of 28 T`s and it`s exceeding 44.
T0 must show as:
T0
----
1384630490
1385148607

and is right now is like:
T0         
--       
1384630490     
1384630490          
1384630490
                                                         1384630490          
1384630490

Comment: I think it`s missing the 2nd element in the $list or it`s saved somewhere else,

Comment: I made a change to reset $i per object. Your description of what should be in T0 doesn't seem to match what you've desribed in the original post.

Comment: Yes exactly now I was writing, I made it..the $i must been reinitiated in the far-inner loop :)

thank you so much!!!